# PHP PDO prepare query issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

The below works as long as the two fields are selected. If neither are selected it works, however my issue is when only **one** of the fields is selected, it doesn't work. It throws the unbound parameters issue.

I've tried setting a false value of 0 to both of the variables, however that won't work because then the query would be select from where = 0.

Ideas?

```
public static function searchProfile($status, $fundamt)
    {
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
        $sql = "SELECT profile_id, profile_name, profile_url, finance_fundingtype, finance_equitypercent, finance_loanrate, finance_loanlength, finance_fundingamount, info_tradingstatus, info_elevatorpitch, info_patentable, info_industry, info_industry1, info_industry2, info_industry3, info_industry4, seeker_logo_url FROM profile_seeker WHERE profile_status = '1' ";

        if ($status) {
        $sql .= "AND info_tradingstatus IN (:status) ";
        }
        if ($fundamt) {
            $sql .= "AND finance_fundingamount <= :fundamt ";
        }

        $query = $database->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':status' => $status, ':fundamt' => $fundamt));
        $profiles = array();
$profiles[$profile->profile_id] = new stdClass();
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->profile_id = $profile->profile_id;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->profile_name = $profile->profile_name;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->profile_url = $profile->profile_url;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->finance_fundingtype = $profile->finance_fundingtype;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->finance_equitypercent = $profile->finance_equitypercent;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->finance_loanrate = $profile->finance_loanrate;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->finance_loanlength = $profile->finance_loanlength;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->finance_fundingamount = $profile->finance_fundingamount;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_tradingstatus = $profile->info_tradingstatus;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_elevatorpitch = $profile->info_elevatorpitch;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_patentable = $profile->info_patentable;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_industry = $profile->info_industry;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_industry1 = $profile->info_industry1;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_industry2 = $profile->info_industry2;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_industry3 = $profile->info_industry3;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_industry4 = $profile->info_industry4;
            $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->seeker_logo_url = $profile->seeker_logo_url;
        }
        return $profiles;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check if the variables are set and that they hold a value that is not 0 and this has a string length longer than 0:

```
if (isset($status) && $status !== 0 && strlen($status) > 0) {
  $sql .= "AND info_tradingstatus IN (:status) ";
}
if (isset($fundamt) && $fundamt!== 0 && strlen($fundamt) > 0) {
  $sql .= "AND finance_fundingamount <= :fundamt ";
}
```

You could also try to bind the parameters manually:

```
$query = $database->prepare($sql);
if (isset($status) && $status !== 0 && strlen($status) > 0) {
  $query ->bindParam(':status',$status);
}
if (isset($fundamt) && $status !== 0 && strlen($fundamt) > 0) {
  $query ->bindParam(':fundamt',$fundamt);
}  
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binding error comes because you forgot to use the same `if exists` statement on your bindings.

Change this...

```
    if ($status) {
    $sql .= "AND info_tradingstatus IN (:status) ";
    }
    if ($fundamt) {
        $sql .= "AND finance_fundingamount <= :fundamt ";
    }
```

and

```
        $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->finance_fundingamount = $profile->finance_fundingamount;
        $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_tradingstatus = $profile->info_tradingstatus;
```

To this...

```
    if (isset($status) && $status != '') {
    $sql .= "AND info_tradingstatus IN (:status) ";
    }
    if (isste($fundamt) && $fundamt != '') {
        $sql .= "AND finance_fundingamount <= :fundamt ";
    }
```

and

```
        if (isset($status) && $status != '') {
        $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->finance_fundingamount = $profile->finance_fundingamount;
        }
        if (isste($fundamt) && $fundamt != '') {
        $profiles[$profile->profile_id]->info_tradingstatus = $profile->info_tradingstatus;
        }
```

This will stop the binding if one or both of the text boxes are empty.